# Powershell Script Foldersize

Tags: powershell

at the Moment i am practice a little bit with Powershell & cmd. Ive googled a bit an found some script which gets me the size of folders in my HDD.
I get some results and im fine with it, but now i want see the foldersize of some subfolder and want to decide between all folders and only subfolders of a folder.

At the moment I don't understand all the commands, so can you guys help me a little bit how i can complete the project successfully?

```
Set-Location c:\users\
$fso = new-object -com Scripting.FileSystemObject
$folderlist = gci -Directory `
 | select @{l='Size'; e={$fso.GetFolder($_.FullName).Size}},FullName `
  | sort Size -Descending `
  | ft @{l='Size [GB]'; e={'{0:N2}    ' -f ($_.Size / 1GB)}},FullName
$folderlist
```

Comment: Have a look at module [TreeSize](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/TreeSize/1.0/Content/TreeSize.psm1) or [directory-treesize](https://github.com/jagilber/powershellScripts/blob/master/directory-treesize.ps1)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is exactly what you want, but try this.

Its pulled directly from https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/weekend-scripter-use-powershell-to-get-folder-sizes/

```
Function Get-FolderSize {
    BEGIN{$fso = New-Object -comobject Scripting.FileSystemObject}
    PROCESS{
        $path = $input.fullname
        $folder = $fso.GetFolder($path)
        $size = $folder.size
    if ($Size -gt 500000) {   # Anything smaller than 500 K, don't print the folder name
        [PSCustomObject]@{‘Name’ = $path;’Size (GB)’ = ("{0:n2}" -f ($Size/1GB)) }
    }


gci -Directory -Recurse -EA 0 | Get-FolderSize | sort size -Descending
```

Whatever folder it is run from you will see each subfolder and its size.

If you want to capture the total size in each folder, that will require only a little bit of re-tweaking

If you run this in the c:\ root folder, it will take a while for any output to appear. Do a test run under c:\user or c:\program files first